# VB.NET Form runs mouse.leave code when I hover over a control

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a form grow and shrink when I enter and leave it with my mouse. However, when the mouse pointer goes over a control, it runs the mouse.leave script. How do I stop this?

Mouse.Leave code

```
Private Sub frm_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim frm1 As Form = DirectCast(sender, Form)
    frm1.Opacity = 0.4
    frm1.Controls.Clear()
    frm1.BringToFront()
    frm1.Size = New Size(20, 50)
    Dim test As Integer = 1
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim yaxis As Integer = 0
    Dim fin As Boolean = False
    Do Until fin = True
        If frm1.Name = "frm" & test Then
            yaxis = counter
            fin = True
        Else
            counter += 10 + frm1.Height
            test += 1
        End If
    Loop
    frm1.Location = New Point(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Size.Width - frm1.Width, yaxis)
End Sub
```

Mouse.enter code

```
    Private Sub frm_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim frm1 As Form = DirectCast(sender, Form)
    Dim lbl As Label = New Label
    Dim btn As Button = New Button
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    For Each ch As Char In frm1.Name
        If IsNumeric(ch) Then
            index = index & ch
        End If
    Next
    index -= 1
    frm1.Controls.Add(lbl)
    lbl.Text = listbox.Items.Item(index)
    lbl.ForeColor = Color.White
    lbl.AutoSize = True
    lbl.Location = New Point((frm1.ClientSize.Width) / 2, (frm1.ClientSize.Height) / 2)
    lbl.Show()
    frm1.Controls.Add(btn)
    btn.Text = "X"
    btn.ForeColor = Color.White
    btn.BackColor = Color.Black
    btn.Font = New Drawing.Font("Arial", 12)
    btn.AutoSize = True
    btn.Location = New Point(200 - btn.Width, 0)
    frm1.Opacity = 1
    frm1.BringToFront()
    frm1.Size = New Size(200, 100)
    Dim test As Integer = 1
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim yaxis As Integer = 0
    Dim fin As Boolean = False
    Do Until fin = True
        If frm1.Name = "frm" & test Then
            yaxis = counter
            fin = True
        Else
            counter += 60
            test += 1
        End If
    Loop
    frm1.Location = New Point(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Size.Width - frm1.Width, yaxis)
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: If this happens then you have assigned the event handler also to your controls. While you check for this then I recommend to add `if frm1 Is Nothing Then Return` after your DirectCast

Comment: it might be that in the course of growing or shrinking a control moves under the mouse.  that would result in Mouse Leave for the form and Mouse Enter on the control.

Comment: @phoenix No it is when i hover over a label or a button

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you enter one of your controls you will generate a MouseEnter event for the control and a [`MouseLeave`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave(v=vs.110).aspx) Event for the form, I would look at checking the position of the mouse and if it was contained in the Form exit the MouseLeave event. Try something like to see if it works for you.

```
If frm1.ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(MousePosition)) Then Exit Sub
```

Also as an aside if you are not going to be using this code with multiple forms you can just use the [`Me`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20fy88e0.aspx) keyword to reference your Form's Properties

```
If Me.ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(MousePosition)) Then Exit Sub
```